# SpringBoot - How can I call a controller from a MQ message listener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jms

I have a JMS listener configured which receives messages from IBM MQ. Once there is a message in the MQ, I want to post the message to my rest controller.

MQ JMS Listener

```
public class MqMessageConsumer {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MqMessageConsumer.class);

    @JmsListener(destination = "${ibm.mq.queue-name}")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        log.info("There is a message in the queue");
        //invoke rest end point
        log.info(message);

        //invoke rest controller in case of MQ call.
    }

}
```

Below is my RestController

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersController.class);

    @PostMapping("/status/checkUser")
    public String getStatus() {
        return "details";
    }
}
```

Any idea how the rest controller can be called from the MQ consumer class?

Comment: You can `@Autowire UsersController` class... Or, better save your messages in database.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a UsersService and use it in both the consumer and controller. In general we keep controller as thin as possible and put business logic in a service

Code can be something like

```
@Service
public class UsersService {
    public String getStatus() {
        return "details";
    }
}

@Component
public class MqMessageConsumer {

    @Autowired UsersService usersService;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${ibm.mq.queue-name}")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        usersService.getStatus();
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired UsersService service;

    @PostMapping("/status/checkUser")
    public String getStatus() {
        return service.getStatus();
    }
}
```